# Setting Gated Check-in build option in Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, checkin, azure-devops

I have added a Visual Studio project in Visual Studio Online at `sitename.visualstudio.com`. How do I enable a gated check-in build for all checkins in the Visual Studio Online web access portal? Do we have option to send code for review in Visual Studio Online's web access portal as well? Where can I find that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To setup Gated Checkin you first need to create a TFS Build, and under the Trigger tab set it to Gated Build.

For Code Review you can create one from the My Work section in Team Explorer (in Visual Studio).

Comment: It's worth noting that Visual Studio Online doesn't allow code review for projects with a Git source control back end